# Access denied while launching Enterprise Architect from Jenkins through COM API python

Tags: python, jenkins, enterprise-architect

I am trying to launch the EA application from Python script, It works well in command line without any problem. The same script throws below error while running it through Jenkins on windows systems.

While trying to access EA through **COM API** it throws this error only in Jenkins

> ```
> (-2147024891, 'Access is denied.', None, None)
> ```

Exactly I am getting this error while the `pythoncom.coCreateinstance()` step.
Users are same on both the occasions.

am using **EA 12**.

```
pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
```

Comment: Probably you run that as service. That's not possible. EA needs a regular user to be run.

Comment: i tried with multiple scenario's . still no luck. do anyone have solution for this

Comment: This comment is as meaningful as the rest of the debugging info you provided use. Voted to close.